# how to show Featured Product home page - NopCommerce?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nopcommerce

I am using NopCommerce  and i want to know how to show Featured Product home page???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every product has `ShowOnHomePage` property that is set from UI. All the products with this property set to `true` will be shown on the home page.

However if you still want all the featured products from all the categories to show up on the home page irrespective of their `ShowOnHomePage` property, then I'd recommend you to extend `ProductService` class and to override `GetAllProductsDisplayedOnHomePage` method which now (ver 1.9) extracts all the products with `ShowOnHomePage` set to `true`.

If you create your own `ProductService` class, be sure to register it in `UnityDependencyResolver` class. To keep the NopCommerce sources intact, I'd recommend to extend `UnityDependencyResolver` class as well (i.e. to inherit a new class from it) and override `ConfigureContainer` method (call the base method from the overriding one). If you define new dependency resolver class, be sure to configure it in `web.config`.